# i3: How to start a program with long startup time on a specified workspace

Tags: x11, i3, window-management, workspaces

Is it possible in my i3 startup file to specifically configure a desktop on which to start a program, but only starting it there once without assigning that program to the desktop in general.

I am aware that a solution exists which involves changing to another workspace, but this leaves me with a major issue:
As soon as I have a program with a 'non-instant' startup time, that program will appear on the last workspace that I switch to and not on the workspace where I want it to be.

In specific, this my current startup file where I did a workaround involving the assignment of atom (which is the program bothering me atm) to workspace 9, which is ok for now but is undesirable in the long run:

```
assign [class="Atom"] $workspace9
exec atom

exec --no-startup-id i3-msg 'workspace $workspace9; exec 
/usr/bin/urxvt'
#exec --no-startup-id i3-msg 'workspace $workspace9; exec /usr/bin/atom'
exec --no-startup-id i3-msg 'workspace $workspace1; exec /usr/bin/urxvt'
```

I would like to get the commented call for atom to execute in the desired way and ditch the assignment method alltogether.

I don't actually think that it is of relevance but just in case: I run Manjaro-Linux, which is based on Arch.

Edit: The following snippet of code works, but still leaves this question open, as it restricts me to open up atom at last and starting my session on that desktop:

```
#assign [class="Atom"] $workspace9
#exec atom

exec --no-startup-id i3-msg 'workspace $workspace9; exec 
/usr/bin/urxvt'
exec --no-startup-id i3-msg 'workspace $workspace1; exec /usr/bin/urxvt'
exec --no-startup-id i3-msg 'workspace $workspace9; exec /usr/bin/atom'
```

This also has the significant drawback that it does not allow for multiple programs starting on different workspaces, if they show the same behavior as atom does.

Comment: I run Kde (on debian Gnu/Linux), I have set up some application to display on certain desktops. They would do this no matter how long they took to start-up.

Answer (score 2):

Wait until the window appears and then send it to the original workspace:

```
#!/bin/bash

activeworkspace=$(i3-msg -t get_workspaces | jq -c '.[] | select(.focused) | .name' --raw-output)
atom &
windowname=atom
xprop -spy -root _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW | \
  while read line ; do 
      if xprop WM_CLASS -id ${line##* } | grep -q $windowname ; then
          i3-msg move "[con_id=\"${line##* }\"]" $activeworkspace
          exit
      fi
  done
```

- At first get the active workspace, use `jq` as an example
- run your program in the background: `atom &`
- Use `xprop -spy` to 'Examine window properties forever, looking for property change events.'
- Act on all new active windows with `while read line`
- Get WM_CLASS of them with `xprop WM_CLASS`, extract the windowid with bash `${line##* }`
- Filter with `grep $windowname`
- Move the window to the original workspace with `i3-msg move ..`

You should stay on the active workspace and a window on this workspace should get focused.

It doesn't work when you have multiple atom windows which get focused between the start and the move of a new atom window. In this case you would have to look for the NET_WM_PID atom instead of WM_CLASS.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to always have specific programs (e.g., Atom) open on particular workspaces, you can use the assign class functionality described in the [i3 User Documentation](https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#assign_workspace)

Run `xprop` from your terminal, and then click on the window (e.g., Firefox) to see what class it belongs to. Look for `WM_CLASS(STRING)`.

Then, it's as simple as putting the following line in your .config file:

```
assign [class="Firefox"] 2
```

Don't forget to restart your instance using (default) `$Mod + Shift + r`

Now, Firefox will always open on workspace 2, regardless of where or when I run it. You could do the same with Atom, and this would free you up to start you desktop wherever you wanted to.

Comment: "without assigning that program to the desktop in general."

Answer (score 0):

Your commented out calls do work for applications that support startup notifcations - in fact, the "Start iceweasel on workspace 3 (once)" example in the [user's guide](http://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#assign_workspace) has nearly the same `exec` command:

```
exec --no-startup-id i3-msg 'workspace 3; exec iceweasel; workspace 1'
```

Atom however [doesn't seem to support startup notifications](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/12388) so you need to keep using the `assign` method.

Comment: Not quite sure if this is at the root of my problem, as commenting out the assignment and startup of atom, then switching to workspace 9 and starting atom there works, but then I do not have the freedom to start on any workspace I like (see edit above). But thanks for your answer (which unfortunately I cannot upvote right now) as it helped specifying the problem.